# What's the difference between isinstance() and np.issubdtype()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'values':[1.23, 3.12, 23.12]}, dtype=float)
```

Running the check:

```
>>> df.values.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Now using isinstance method:

```
>>> isinstance(df.values.dtype, float)
False
```

Now using issubdtype method:

```
>>> np.issubdtype(df.values.dtype, float)
True
```

By reading the doc.

**Syntax  isinstance (object, classinfo)**

**object**: An object instance.

*I'm passing a ndarray object (Can I consider this as an object instance?)*

**classinfo**: A class, type or a tuple containing classes, types or other tuples.

*I'm passing the float which is a type, which is fine.*

The question is: why is the isinstance not returning true in the above example? and what's the difference between isinstance and issubdtype?

Comment: `issubdtype` works with two types (and checks if one type is a subtype of the other), whereas `isinstance` works with an *object* and a type, and checks if the object is an instance of that type.

Comment: and why is the example I gave returning false?

Comment: because `dtype('float')` is not a float object (a float object would be `0.0`, `3.14`, `np.nan`, etc). It is a type.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: It's not even a type. NumPy's dtype system is a separate system from the ordinary Python type system. `dtype('float')` is a dtype, not a type.

Comment: "I'm passing a ndarray object" - no you're not. That would be `df.values`, not `df.values.dtype`.

Answer (score 1):

> why is the `isinstance` not returning true in the above example?

Because `df.values.dtype` returns a *type*, not an object of that type. Indeed, `df.values.dtype` returns `dtype('float')`, but that is *not* a `float` *object*. It is a `dtype` object.

The `issubdtype` takes *a dtype, type, or a string* and checks if the first type is the same or a subclass of the second type. We can inspect the *method resolution order* of the type, and see:

```
>>> df.values.dtype.type.__mro__
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.floating'>, <class 'numpy.inexact'>, <class 'numpy.number'>, <class 'numpy.generic'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so the type is indeed a subclass of `float`. But it is *not* an instance of a `float`. An instance of a `float` is for example `0.0`, `3.14`, `np.nan`, etc. If we inspect the type of these objects, we get:

```
>>> type(0.0)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(3.14)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
```

Whereas the type of for the `dtype('float')` is `dtype`, and for `float`, it is just `type`:

```
>>> type(df.values.dtype)
<class 'numpy.dtype'>
>>> type(float)
<class 'type'>
```

We can thus check that the `df.values.dtype` is an instance of `dtype` and obtain:

```
>>> isinstance(df.values.dtype, np.dtype)
True
```

Comment: You're mixing up dtypes and types here. While doing so *usually* doesn't cause problems, for a question like this, the distinction is much more important. For example, while `numpy.issubdtype(df.values.dtype, float)` is `True` (currently because `float` is special-cased, and in some future NumPy version because `float` gets `dtype` implicitly called on it), `issubclass(df.values.dtype, float)` raises a `TypeError`.

Answer (score -1):

First, `df.values.dtype` is an instance of the numpy's class [dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html), not of the Python's class `float`:

```
>>> df.values.dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> isinstance(df.values.dtype, np.dtype)
True

>>> isinstance(df.values.dtype, float)
False
```

Second, from the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L365-L425) of the function `np.issubdtype` we see that when calling `np.issubdtype(df.values.dtype, float)`, the first argument `df.values.dtype` is converted to `df.values.dtype.type` (i.e. `np.float64`) and the second argument `float` to `np.floating`. Then what is returned is `issubclass(np.float64, np.floating)`, which is of course `True`.

So, in short, `df.values.dtype` is a *subclass* of `np.floating`, not an instance of `float`.